# When I am querying data from database it doesn't passes to the base class in C# and SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, inheritance, dapper

I have a class `Customer` which inherits from class `Person`, but when I am querying data from the database, it doesn't pass to the base class `Person`. Data is just passed to `Customer` class.

The `CustomerInfo` database table data has columns:

```
Id - FirstName - LastName - NickName - Address - RegistrationDate
```

I use Dapper to connect to my SQLite database.

Why does this happen, and I want to pass data to the constructor but I don't know how.

```
public class PersonModel
{
    int Id;
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;

    public PersonModel() { }

    public PersonModel(string firstName, string lastName, int id = 0)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }
}

public class CustomerModel : PersonModel
{
    string NickName;
    string Address;
    string RegistrationDate;

    public CustomerModel() { }

    public CustomerModel(string firstName, string lastName,
        string address, string registrationDate = "",
        string nickName = "", int id = 0) : base(firstName, lastName, id)
    {
        NickName = nickName;
        Address = address;
        RegistrationDate = registrationDate;
    }

    public string FullInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{GetFullName()} {RegistrationDate}";
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerDataAccess
{
    public static List<CustomerModel> LoadCustomers()
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionStrings()))
        {
            IEnumerable<CustomerModel> output = cnn.Query<CustomerModel>("SELECT * FROM CustomerInfo", new DynamicParameters());
            
            return output.ToList();
        }
    }

    private static string LoadConnectionStrings(string id = "Default")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is that you have a default constructor and a parameterized constructor. Dapper is using the default constructor which is why the fields in `PersonModel` are null/default. You can change the access modifier to private for the customer model -  `private CustomerModel() { }` - and it should pick the parameterized constructor instead.

However, when you're using a parameterized constructor you need to **match the order of the columns returned from the query with the order of the parameters in the constructor you want to use**.  There is no guarantee of the order the columns will be returned when using `select * from...`.

So, you should update the SQL query to:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, RegistrationDate, Nickname, Id FROM CustomerInfo
```

---

However, I do think you'd benefit from using public properties/fields as it would give you more options/control when mapping the data.

Comment: I have tried your solution but the problem still exist.

Comment: Have you tried removing both default constructors? @KyrillosGaber

Comment: @KyrillosGaber what errors are you getting? I had errors when trying your solution and would be interested to know if you also got the same errors

Comment: when I delete the constructor ```public CustomerModel() { }``` I got this error  constructor or one matching signature (System.String FirstName, System.String LastName, System.String Address, System.String RegestrationDate, System.String NickName, System.Int64 Id) is required for StoreManagementLibrary.CustomerModel materialization'

Comment: And don't you have such a constructor with: `public CustomerModel(string firstName, string lastName, string address, string registrationDate = "", string nickName = "", int id = 0)`? Keep the parameterized constructors but remove the parameterless constructor. The order of the fields returned from SQL should match the order of the parameters in the constructor @KyrillosGaber

Comment: Yes this is my constructor ```public CustomerModel(string firstName, string lastName, string address, string regestrationDate = "", string nickName = "", int id = 0) : base(firstName, lastName, id) { NickName = nickName; Address = address; RegestrationDate = regestrationDate; }``` . But I don't know to make constructor match the signature @haldo

Comment: @KyrillosGaber Do you have null values in the database (for any of the optional fields)? I think that's the problem, because it works fine for me, unless I have null values in the DB for say, the `Id` field. Then I get the error you're seeing.

Comment: Ok thanks my dear it works @haldo

Comment: One of the problems is ```int``` data type and ```INTEGER``` data type in sqlite and I solved it by using ````long``` instead of ```int``` @haldo

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you got it working @KyrillosGaber

Answer (score 0):

your query returns only customerinfo table column, it should have a join with a person table, if you want to return info from both tables.

IMHO I don't see what are you going to win using constructor instead of getters setters.Try this

```
public class PersonModel
{
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public  string FirstName {get; set;}
        public string LastName {get; set;}
        ....and so on
}
```

the same with another class

Comment: The CustomerInfo database table data is: Id - FirstName - LastName - NickName - Address - RegestrationDate. when I query database just NickName, Address and RegestrationDate pass to customer class but FirstName, LastName and Id doesn't pass.

Comment: @KyrillosGaber As I advised you alreagy and getters and setters. Forget about constructors. Use them only in the case if you can not live without them.

Comment: I tried to separate person table from customer table but same problem exist.

Comment: I think the problem when data pass to class automatically, Instead of that I want to catch the data and pass it manually. But I don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is `int` data type in c# and `INTEGER` data type in sqlite doesn't match and I solved it by using `long`  instead of  `int`